# error logging android application

Tags: android

Good morning,
Is there a way for me to track errors that occur in my application? I currently write the errors to a file in the SD card of the device. But most of the times the device doesn't have an sd card. I also tried to use the local database but still having errors that crash the application without notice.

thanks in advam

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

You can try [Application Crash Report for Android](http://acra.ch).

**OR**

You can use bugsense that show all the uncaught and caught exception occur in app. These data will be shown on dashboard of bugsense.

Check here [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/). It upload the error message on dashboard immediately.

Comment: I stumbled on apphance.com and i think it is a good try. thanks.